# How to test if an instance is corrupted?

Tags: c++

I found a bug in an existing program (c++ auto-generated code) in this method :

```c
void _CallStyle _WFObjectVarAsStringExtractEFAgent::LoadValue(Pointer __VarAddress, aType theVarType) {
   absolute(tpPointer, VarAddress, __VarAddress);
   aLightObject Obj = nil;

   Obj = aLightObject(*VarAddress);

   if ( Obj == Nil ) {

      this->SetValue("");
   } else {
      this->SetValue(Obj->StringExtract(this->ExtractKind, this->ExtractParam, 0));
   }
   this->Lock();
   if ( Obj == Nil ) {
      this->Disable();
   } else {
      this->Enable();
   }
}
```

Sometime the line `Obj = aLightObject(*VarAddress);` returns not a valid `aLightObject` instance neither `Nil` (but an corrupted `aLightObject` instance).

So in the following line `if ( Obj == Nil ) {` we enter in the `else` bloc and the program fails when trying to execute the `Obj->StringExtract` call.

How can i test is the `Obj` instance is valid ?

Comment: you're probably better off tracking down and eliminating the corruption, rather than trying to deal with it

Comment: Well that entirely depends on what “valid” means for you, doesn’t it? There is no universal concept of “valid” other than “in a state allowed by the standard”.

Comment: Write correct code so that your objects are always "valid" (whatever that means).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker : I've tried to find out the reasons why the object is sometime corrupted but some portions of the code aren't visible (especially the `aLightObjet` class).

Comment: @KonradRudolph : The debugger shows that the class of `Obj` is `aLightObject` but it doesn't have all the methods of `aLightObject` !

Comment: why isn't the code visible?

Comment: @KerrekSB : "I found a bug in an existing program **(c++ auto-generated code)**"

Comment: @mr_peck That’s impossible. (And no, I’m not being hyperbolic, this is actually impossible, you’re reading the debugger output wrong.)

Comment: @Default : proprietary software => my employer only buy some portions of the sources.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : ![debug output](http://npic.imagup.com/1/1180265006.PNG).

Comment: @mr_peck Wow, I take that back. That’s mighty interesting, and completely invalid in C++ (obviously). I’m not sure that you can debug this in any reliable way since it obviously relies on undefined behaviour. I’d say: annoy your library vendor, they probably messed up. (And finally: yes, it absolutely makes sense to call this “invalid” in the C++ sense *but* it would be nice to include this information in the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a pointer is not NULL/NIL/Nil or some other "recognisable 'isn't a pointer'" then it is almost imossible to determine if it's a valid pointer or not. Sure, if it's "nearly NULL", you can perhaps have a chance with some unportable code that checks something along the lines of:

```
 ptrdiff_t diff = NULL - reinterpret_cast<char *>(ptr);
 if (diff < -100000) cout << "Bad pointer" << ptr << endl;
```

You can also do a check if the object is a valid pointer and contains something that you know what it's supposed to be. The typical way to do that is to have a "magic", e.g.

```
 class myobject
 {
    public: 
       int magic;
    ...
       myobject() : magic(1234567)     // Make sure it's different for each type of object. 
       {
         ...
       }
     ....
 };

 ...
     if (obj->magic != 1234567)  cout << "Object is not right type..." << endl;
```

However, this DOES NOT WORK if `obj` is just some completely arbitrary value between 0...2<sup>n</sup> where n is the bitness of the machine. It will just crash as badly as if you didn't check it in the first place.