# c++ Testing for a missing callback function

Tags: c++, exception, callback

EDIT:  added backquotes to callback template.  The interface was reading the asterisks as markdown indicators, not just as asterisks!

In a Windows DLL/Linux SO I am writing, I give the user app a way to register a callback function.  Works great.  The callback prototype looks like `(void)(*callback)(void*);`

I was having a fit of paranoia while writing the docs and realized, I have no really good way to know if the registered address is valid.  The only feedback is either a crash or call the callback inside a try/catch.

I have no idea what exception would be thrown if the callback did not exist and who-knows-what executed.  NOt even really sure that the call to "nowhere" could recover itself enough to generate the exception instead of a crash.

Yes, I know it's the user's problem.  Just trying to be thoughtful and maybe help the user understand his bug.

So, what exception would this throw?  Windows and Linux answers please if they differ.

Or, is there a better way to approach this without having to use an exception catch to detect the missing function?

Comment: You can only test for NULL and call the function if callback != NULL. There is no reliable portable way to test callback address for validity, or recover after invalid address call.

Comment: If you want to call a callback function from you shared library the only test can work is to compare a callback pointer with null. =) There is no better way. If your program get a segfault you can't recover from this. The only way to run extern code without crashing the current application - is to fork the process and execute something there to see what happens and get data from the forked process. But a) User never expects the process to fork. b) Even if he expects this, he need to close all resources that can't be shared before callback - and this is generally impossible.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Actually, running plug-ins in a separate process (rather than a separate thread) is more or less standard procedure now adays.  Almost all browsers do it.

Comment: @JamesKanze Running plugins in a separate process is a good thing. If you are the application developer you can prepare the process state for the fork. But this task is reversed. The plugin wants to fork the application to dodge the crash. Assuming that callbacks are used for really reasonable task it's generally impossible for developer to prepare the app for this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to recover. Similarly, you cannot recover if the callback contains a line like `*(int*)(0x1234) = 5;`. Just live with it.

As a C++ library developer, you're not in the business of making sure that nothing ever crashes. You merely provide code that does what it promises when used the way you document.

Answer (score 3):

A bit off-topic, but callbacks in the form of `void(*)()`, i.e. taking 0 arguments, are less than useful. A useful C-style callback accepts a user specified argument, so that the user can find the state corresponding to the callback. E.g.:

```
typedef void callback_fn(void* user_arg);

callback_id register_callback(callback_fn* callback, void* user_arg);
void unregister_callback(callback_id);
```

Without `user_arg` the user of your callback will be forced to use a global variable to store state corresponding to the callback function.

Comment: +1 for being more observant than me.  I added backquotes to the callback template.  The interface was reading the asterisks as markdown indicators, not just as asterisks!  The template really was `(void)(*callback)(void *)`

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe is rather unlikely. I have never seen such handling anywhere. The program would just crash and ruin its user.

But your concern is valid, because the failure root cause (assigning wrong address) and its manifestation (call to invalid address) can be so far away from each other that it could be very hard to identify it.

All I could advise here is to "fail fast and loud". For instance, you could do test call of the callback whenever it is assigned. This will still lead to crash, but now in the stack trace user will see where it all started from.

Again, this is not something an ordinary library user would expect...

Comment: I am already doing the callback in the RegisterCallback() function.  Started out as a development test that just seemed too good to remove.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered here:

[How to test if an instance is corrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926263/c-how-to-test-if-an-instance-is-corrupted)
(completely different type of question, but same applies)

If the pointer is "not recognisable NULL or similar", then there is no way, in code, to tell if it's valid or not.

You also can't use `try/catch` to capture the failure, as "failure to execute the code" does not result in a throw.

Since this a "programmer error", I don't believe it's a big issue. Programmers can do what they like with their own code anyway, so whatever mechanism you add, it's going to be possible to circumvent in some way or another.

Comment: "You can't make anything foolproof because fools are so ingenious." from the book _Murphy's Law_ from sometime in the mid- to kate 1970s.

Comment: Indeed. If you make it MORE foolproof, someone will just come up with a better fool...

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there's no way to check, but...  Is it 
really necessary?  I'm all in favor of defensive programming,
but the only way you can possibly get a pointer to a function
(other than a null pointer) is by taking the address of
a function.  Some compilers *do* allow explicitly converting
a pointer to an object to a pointer to function, despite the
fact that the standard requires a diagnostic in such cases.  But
even then, the client code needs an explicit cast to screw up.
And unlike objects, functions life through out the lifetime of
the program, so you cannot have a problem with a dangling
pointer—a pointer which was once valid, but isn't any
more.  There is, in fact, practically no way to get an invalid
pointer to a function except intentionally (the only way that
occurs to me is if the unload a DLL with the function), and if
someone intentionally wants to screw up, there's no way you'll
be able to prevent it.